# Collinear points in $\mathbb{K}^n$, $k_1k_2k_3 = (k_1-1)(k_2-1)(k_3-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Could you tell me how to prove that given three non collinear points in $\mathbb{K}^n$: $A, \ B, \ C$, the following three points:

$A_1 = k_1B + (1-k_1)C, \ \ B_1=k_2C + (1-k_2)A, \ \ C_1=k_3A + (1-k_3)B$

are collinear $\iff \ \ \ k_1k_2k_3= (k_1-1)(k_2-1)(k_3-1)$?

I've tried equating lines generated by $A_1$ and $B_1$, $A_1$ and $C_1$ and $B_1$ and $C_1$ but I got lost in the calculations.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1 : If the dimensionality is $3$ (show that one can always assume wlog that this is the case), then $A_1,B_1,C_1$ are collinear iff
the determinant $d=[\overrightarrow{OA_1},\overrightarrow{OB_1},\overrightarrow{OC_1}]$ is zero.

Hint 2 : Show that

$$
\Bigg|
\begin{matrix}
0 & k_1 & 1-k_1  \\
1-k_2 & 0 & k_2  \\
k_3 & 1-k_3 & 0  \\
\end{matrix}
\Bigg|=k_1k_2k_3-(k_1-1)(k_2-1)(k_3-1).
$$

Comment: I just want to make sure if I understand this correctly. In the first row is $k_1$ the distance between $A_1$ and $B_1$?

Comment: No, $k_1,k_2$ and $k_3$ are exactly as in your original question.

Comment: Could you explain to me exactly how this matrix is constructed? Are those entries coordinates of $A_1, B_1, C_1$ in basis $A, B, C$?

Comment: One expresses the coordinates of the vectors $OA_1,OB_1,OC_1$ relatively to the basis $(OA,OB,OC)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link on [collinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity#Collinearity_of_points_whose_coordinates_are_given).

If you look at the analogous matrix constructed with the $A_1, B_1,$ and $C_1$, you'll see the rows corresponding to those vectors must be linearly dependent. Writing out the linear dependence relation and rearranging for each of the $k_i$s, you'll see why you get that $k_1 k_2 k_3$ equation.

Comment: i cannot comment on the other answer, but it should be said that its approach only makes sense in $\mathbb{k}^3$

Comment: No, the other answer makes sense in any dimension. Because everything can be reduces to the subspace generated by the vectors $OA,OB,OC$, and this subspace has dimension $3$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If $A$ and $B$ (say) lie on a line, then the three vectors will generate a two-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Indeed, but if you add the origin, that makes four points and a three-dimensional subspace

Comment: adding the origin won't change the subspace generated? can you be more specific with what you mean by "reduces to the subspace generated by the vectors"?

Comment: Consider the subspace $F$ generated by vectors $OA,OB$ and $OC$. This is a three-dimensional subspace of the initial space. Then $OA_1,OA_2$, and $OA_3$ are all in $F$.